# Reinstall software without re-downloading from software center?

Tags: software-installation, apt

I have installed FlightGear, a flight simulator. Some of the game's main files have been tampered with by a third-party app and the game no longer works.

It's a very big download and as I'm on a very limited bandwidth connection, I would like to know if there is a way to re-install the game from the installation files that Elementary OS's Software Center originally downloaded - instead of having to uninstall it and then re-download and re-install it all over again?

Comment: It should do that by default if its still available in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: Oh. Awesome. Thanks @jordanm - I could've tried but really didn't wanna take the chance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall package_name` to reinstall the package, files belong to it will be overwritten automatically.

To find the package name, run `dpkg -l | grep -i flightgear` to figure out. There could be more than one package, usually you only need to reinstall the `*-data` package